# Copy .sh file from my local computer to the remote server

Tags: file, sh, remote-desktop

I have a test.sh file and I want to copy this file from my local computer to the remote server. How I can do this? I tried using `scp` but it does't work. Maybe I done something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine `hello.txt` is the file you want to move. Directory you are standing on contains this file.

Run `scp hello.txt root@YOUR_SERVER:/root`.

This will copy `hello.txt` to your root's home directory. Run `cd ~` on your server and you will see your file.

In this example I used `root` account, but you can also use another account too

Answer (score 0):

```
scp user@IP-address:exact-path-of-file-you-want-to-copy
```

Then, enter the password for the remote system.

Alternatively, you can try this:

```
scp your.sh Server-Name@Ip-address:Path-in-Server
```

And then, enter the password of the remote system.

Comment: I've edited your answer to improve the formatting. It was unclear if, on the last line, you ended for the password to be part of the command or not. If you did, please edit your answer to clarify that. Regardless, please review my edits so you can see how to provide this type of formatting in the future.